# need help to fix spring boot project

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to add new name,lastName and email. After clicking save button I got an error message " Field error in object 'employee' on field 'id' " 
How can I fix this error . I'm using spring boot with thymeleaf and jquery.

[image]

And

[image]

project link is : **[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0bfihsoyj4otjm/ChadThymleaf4-db-newWindow.zip?dl=0)**

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your column id as **Integer** and dont pass it from UI or pass value as null object. If you want to keep it int then always pass 0 from UI. Passing empty String will always raise exception until you dont have your own messageConverter handling.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name=id)
private Integer id;
```

Comment: I changed int to Integer but is still the same error

Comment: After changing you need to ensure that your UI(caller of api) must not send that key in your request json or must send null object as value of the key.

Comment: When i change input type="hidden" to input type="text"  and i  enter a number in 'id' textfield , than the project is working ,but i don't want to show id field in the form,and the id field in mysql is auto increment.

Comment: if you are using input type="hidden" then pass any default value say 0. If you dont pass value then it will go as empty string by default.  And value of 0 will not affect your auto generated id but will help spring in proper mapping.  ex :   <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="0">

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring as the 'id' field of Employee entity is blank/empty string. As per the 'id' definition from Employee.java, it should be an integer value. You need to pass some integer value to this 'id' field of employee object before it is saved. Use the following technique to let the application use database sequence.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq_generator", sequenceName = "my_seq", allocationSize=50)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private int id;
```

Comment: @NinoosAlKatoni are you passing any value to this variable? I see you declared it as hidden parameter in the form without assigning any value to it. which is then passed to the server side to be saved in the data base and that's where it is giving this error. You need to make sure you're assigning some value to the field 'id' either by passing or setting some thing in your code or define a sequence in database and add relevant annotation in your entity class so that the 'id' value is automatically take from database sequence.

Comment: When i change input type="hidden" to input type="text"  and i  enter a number in 'id' textfield , than the project is working ,but i don't want to show id field in the form,and the id field in mysql is auto increment.

Comment: In that case, you need not to declare that any where in the form. Just pass the rest of the fields and make sure you have decorated the 'id' field in the Entity class with relevant annotations. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: it's same error, 'Edit' button is working but 'New' button is not working, although 'Edit' and 'New' buttons are the same, 'Edit' button retrieve data and when i click save the data is saved but 'New' button does not retrieve data, you can check the project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change parameter named id as Integer not int on your Controller. Primitive int variable can not be null.

Comment: I changed but is still the same issue